# proving $E$ is $\nu$-null iff $|\nu| (E)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I am having trouble proving the converse of the statement below. So far I have that $\nu (E)=0$, but that doesn't mean that $E$ is necessarily $\nu$-null. I can't seem to find a way to prove that if $A\subseteq E$ and $A$ is measurable, then $\nu (A)=0$. Below is a print screened image of what I have so far. Some guidance would be appreciated! Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A\subset E$, then $|\nu|(A)\le |\nu|(E)=0$ (monotonicity), so $|\nu|(A)=0$.

By the argument you have in the "$\Leftarrow$" direction, it follows that $\nu(A)=0$.

Comment: I didn't think that I could use monotonicity because $\nu$ is a signed measure, but $|\nu|$ is a positive measure, so of course I can!

Comment: @Sarah Exactly that is the point.