# Let $\nu$ be a signed measure, then E is $\nu$-null iff $|\nu|(E)=0$

Tags: measure-theory

I am having trouble with understanding the proof of the forward direction. In all the proofs I have seen it's always the case that the following fact is implied.

Taking a Hahn Decomposition $X=P\cup N$.

$\nu(E)=0 \Rightarrow \nu(E\cap P)=0$ since $E\cap P\subset E$. However why is this true? An example, [proving $E$ is $\nu$-null iff $|\nu| (E)=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668986/proving-e-is-nu-null-iff-nu-e-0).

I can only deduce $0=\nu(E)=\nu(E\cap P)+\nu (E\cap N)$ and $\nu(E\cap P)\geq 0$ since it is a subset of P, but $\nu (E\cap N)$ could still be negative.

Alternatively, are there any other proofs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your reasoning is right. Your problem seems to be with the definition of null set for signed measures.

Let $\nu$ be a signed measure on the $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$, then the definition of  $\nu$-null set is:

> **Definition:** $E$ is $\nu$-null set if for all $A\in \Sigma$ and $A\subseteq E$ we have $\nu(A)=0 \phantom{i}$.

Note that if $E$ is a $\nu$-null set then $\nu(E) =0$. But the implication does not work in the reverse direction. That is to say: we may have  $\nu(E) =0$ without $E$ being a $\nu$-null set.

Let us prove that if $E$ is a  $\nu$-null then $|\nu|(E)=0$.

**Proof:** Taking a Hahn Decomposition $X=P\cup N$.

Since $E$ is a  $\nu$-null and $E\cap P\subset E$, we have $\nu(E\cap P)=0$.
Since $E$ is a  $\nu$-null and $E\cap N\subset E$, we have $\nu(E\cap N)=0$.
So we have
$$|\nu|(E) = \nu(E\cap P)+ \nu(E\cap P)=0$$

**Remark:** The implication $$\nu(E)=0 \Rightarrow \nu(E\cap P)=0 \textrm{ since } E\cap P\subset E$$ is actually wrong. The correct statement is
$$E \textrm{ is a } \nu\textrm{-null set }   \Rightarrow \nu(E\cap P)=0 \textrm{ since } E\cap P\subset E$$

Comment: Ahh to think that it was such a small detail! I've looked through my notes and the provided lecture notes and it wasn't mentioned that the null set definition was changed at all. But it is defined that way in Folland, the recommended textbook.

Comment: @Henry: On what page of Folland is this definition of a $\nu$-null set given? I've looked through the book but can't find it...

Comment: @Leonidas , It is in Folland chapter 3 just before 3.2 Lemma. It is the definition of **positive** (resp. **negative** , **null**) set for a signed measure.

Comment: @Ramiro: Found it, thank you!